# Does latest version of StackExcahnge.Redis is supported in .NetFramework 4.0?

Tags: stackexchange.redis

I tried to add the StackExchange.Redis in my project file and got the below error

"Could not install package 'StackExchange.Redis 2.0.601'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Does latest version of StackExcahnge.Redis is supported in .NetFramework 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

According to [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/), the current version (v2.0.601) has a minimum requirement of .Net Framework 4.6.1